# Is there a way to query data with like clause with Hazelcast PredicateBuilder?

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast PredicateBuilder(https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6-EA3/javadoc/com/hazelcast/query/PredicateBuilder.html#filter(com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryContext)) and EntryObject(https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6-EA3/javadoc/com/hazelcast/query/EntryObject.html) to query a Data store.

Is there a way to combine these functions to get a `LIKE` clause? For example if I have animals table, which has id and name field like this `Animal(id, name)` and two rows - `Animal(1, grey rabbit)` and `Animal(2, blue rabbit)` and I'd like to get a query like this:

```
SELECT id FROM animal WHERE name LIKE '%rabbit%'
```

Comment: There is a Predicates class, that has like function in it and EntryObject has private function addPredicate. It's really weird that there is no function for like in EntryObject class, but there is a Predicate for it in Predicates class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SqlPredicate, something like that:

```
map.values(new SqlPredicate("name like '%rabbit%');
```

or

```
map.values(new SqlPredicate("__key.name like '%rabbit%');
```

if you wish to query keys.

Remeber about all the performance problems when using 'like'.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Although I found another way to use build in predicates with map().values(Predicates.ilike("name", "%rabbit%")

Comment: That looks good also. One difference is (I don't know your use case, so it might not be important for you) is that you can create complex queries with SqlPredicate. You can say you want all keys where age > 15 and name like '%rabbit%' and I don't think it is possible with Predicates.ilike.

Comment: I didn't need a complex query, but I will keep that in mind for the future. Thank you for the answer!